# JQuery disappears when wrapping datatable in a form

Tags: jquery, forms, datatable, xhtml, selectbooleancheckbox

I'm trying to create an h:datatable that has a selectBooleanCheckbox at each row, so I have wrapped the dataTable in an h:form element.  My dataTable also needs to support pagination and searching.  This works fine until I wrap the table in the h:form, at which point all the JQuery elements for pagination and searching disappear.  I have wrapped the entire table in a form instead of just a column because there are submit buttons on the page that need to be wrapped in the same form as the table (as far as I understand).

Here is my xhtml :

```
                    <h:form>
                        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.tableProperties()}"
                                     var="property" styleClass="responsive small-table"
                                     id="propertiesSelect">

                            <h:column headerClass="column10">
                                <f:facet name="header">Properties</f:facet>

                                <div class="medium-12 columns checkbox" align="right">
                                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="propertySelect"
                                                             value="#{bean.selectedProperties[property.propertyId]}">
                                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                    <h:outputLabel for="propertySelect" class="">
                                        <h:outputText value=""/>
                                    </h:outputLabel>
                                </div>
                            </h:column>

                            <h:column headerClass="">
                                <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>

                                <span class="">
                                   <c:if test="#{property.name != null}">
                                       <span class="">#{property.name}</span>,
                                   </c:if>
                                </span>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>

                        <div class="row actions">
                            <div class="medium-6 columns">
                                <h:commandButton class="button radius secondary small expand cancel"
                                                 value="#{localization['global.button.cancel']}"
                                                 action="#{bean.exit}" immediate="true"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="medium-6 columns">
                                <h:commandButton class="button radius small expand"
                                                 value="#{localization['global.button.continue']}"
                                                 action="#{bean.submit()}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <f:event listener="#{bean.validateProperties}" type="postValidate" param=""/>

                    </h:form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#propertiesSelect").DataTable({
        searching: true,
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [5, 10, 15, -1],
            [5, 10, 15, "All"]
        ],
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true

    });

});
```

So the JQuery works if I remove the form, but the selectBooleanCheckboxes and commandButtons do not, and vice versa.

How can I do both?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in your HTML output, how is the table been generated I mean whats the order of the table, it should be as per the documentation suggest

```
<table id="xyz">
<thead>
<th></th>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

once the order is been identified DataTables takes the table and transform in to the required table as per the initiation. Also I found some clue if I check the logs while I was working on a requirement like this. One More thing I don't think datatables has searching as an option, if you are required to have a search option it could be done with  `"bFilter":true,` or by default DataTables has the filter option.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a form around the table.  You can simply catch the button clicks in your jQuery based on class names, and action appropriately.  Use the Datatables API to get values you need from the data model.

Alternatively, if you do opt to go with a form around the datatable (which I don't recommend) you'll be forced to event.preventDefault() on button click events such as the paging up/down buttons.  Remember, any button click inside a form will submit that form, which wouldn't work on a paging button click!

Comment: Sorry I am new to this.  The values that are being selected in my dataTable eventually need to be passed to a Java Backing Bean.  The button click invokes Java code, which uses a map that is populated based on which values have been selected in the datatable.  Since this is the case, and I am not only using jQuery, do I need to wrap the datatable in a form?

Comment: I guess the best way to explain it is that there's several different ways to come at this.  I'm certainly not a Java guru, though I've worked in several java shops.  Since I'm on a UI Team, I approach it mostly from the javascript end -- you have jquery available to you, it'd be simple to catch the click events of the buttons with a $('selector').on('click') for example, then action your page accordingly.  Wrapping a form around a table (which I don't think technically makes sense from a W3 standpoint) will open cans of worms like the button example I gave you on pagination.  I'd avoid that.